# How to receive drag and drop from Apple Address book in Qt 4.4 on Mac OS X 10.5/10.6

Tags: c++, macos, qt, mime-types

I am trying to trap drag and drop events from the standard Apple address book app to my Qt app. This code works fine with Qt 4.4. on Mac OS X 10.4:

```
void 
MyView::contentsDropEvent( QDropEvent* e )
{
    QList<QUrl> urls = e->mimeData()->urls();
    ...
```

I can then use the URL to get the vCard. Marvellous.

But from Mac OS X 10.5 the apple address book no longer seems to support text/uri-list. So e->mimeData()->urls() returns an empty list. Worse still, e->mimeData()->formats() returns an empty list. How do I find out which vCards they dragged?

Here is a comment from a Nokia Qt engineer on this problem:

> "Adressbook stopped providing drop
>   data as text/uri-list compatible
>   flavor data in OS 10.5. Not much we
>   can do about that. The flavor they
>   provide instead is 'public.vcard'. We
>   could put up support for this as an
>   implementation request, but my gut
>   feeling is that this is too
>   application specific, and can just as
>   well be implemented by the app
>   developer by subclassing QMacMimeData"

But there is no QMacMimeData in the Qt 4.4 or 4.5 documentation. Any ideas at how I can find out what they dragged?

Comment: QMacMimeData is implemented in src/gui/kernel/qclipboard_mac.cpp sometimes they rely on their "gut feeling" too much

Comment: I found a QMacPasteboardMime class: http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.4/qmacpasteboardmime.html . But I have no idea if I can use that to access the public.vcard data. I can't find any example code.

Comment: Did you report this bug in http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com ?

Comment: It was entered in the old Trolltech bug tracking system quite some time ago:
http://www.trolltech.com/developer/task-tracker/index_html?id=193257&method=entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

richardmg of Qt/Nokia kindly supplied me with some example code. I have filled in some of the gaps. This now works fine on Mac OS X 10.5.

```
#include <QtGui>

class VCardMime : public QMacPasteboardMime
{
    public:
    VCardMime() : QMacPasteboardMime(MIME_ALL)
    { }

    QString convertorName()
    {
        return QString("VCardMime");
    }

    bool canConvert(const QString &mime, QString flav)
    {
        return mimeFor(flav) == mime;
    }

    QString mimeFor(QString flav)
    {
        if (flav == QString("public.vcard"))
            return QString("application/x-mycompany-VCard");
        return QString();
    }

    QString flavorFor(const QString &mime)
    {
        if (mime == QString("application/x-mycompany-VCard"))
            return QString("public.vcard");
        return QString();
    }

    QVariant convertToMime(const QString &mime, QList<QByteArray> data, QString flav)
    {
        QByteArray all;
        foreach ( QByteArray i, data )
        {
            all += i;
        }
        return QVariant( all );
    }

    QList<QByteArray> convertFromMime(const QString &mime, QVariant data, QString flav)
    {
        // Todo: implement!
        return QList<QByteArray>();
    }

};

class TestWidget : public QWidget
{

public:
    TestWidget() : QWidget(0)
    {
        new VCardMime();
        setAcceptDrops(true);
    }

    void contentsDropEvent(QDropEvent* e)
    {
        if ( e->mimeData()->hasFormat( "application/x-mycompany-VCard" ) )
        {                
            QString s = QString( e->mimeData()->data( "application/x-mycompany-VCard" ) );

            // s now contains text of vcard

            e->acceptProposedAction();
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    TestWidget wid1;
    wid1.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```